# EJBs are not updating when hot-deployed on JBOSS

Tags: java, deployment, jboss, ejb-3.0

i have a jboss 5.1.0 AS and ejb 3.0 bean.

the problem is when i redeploy(hot) the bean to the server using ant build file, no changes are made. i have to restart the server each time i redeploy the bean. the operating system is ubuntu 9.04.

i've already done the following:
1) checked whether the bean jar file is built correctly.
2) checked the roles(i thought about some access issues).
3) checked everywhere for some kind of cache.

but still i have no luck.

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where do you copy your EAR? You should copy it to deploy directory. In this case JBoss usually knows to re-deploy the application. Usually but not always.

So, try to do the following. First, verify that you are really copying the EAR to deploy directory. Second, stop JBoss and cleanup work and tmp directories. Now start jboss, wait a couple of minutes and copy the EAR to deploy directory. I hope it will work.

Note that JBoss is not able to redeploy application many times. According to my experience it works 5-10 times. Then you get OutOfMemoryError (PermGen). At this point you have to restart JBoss anyway.

Comment: thanks for the answer. i copy the bean to $JBOSS_HOME/server/default/deploy directory. anyway, it looks like some kind of magic. just for a test i renamed all the classes and the bean name but the it is still being deployed with its old name.

Comment: i stopped the server, cleaned the tmp folder and this helped. thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like he's hot deploying an EJB jar somewhere, maybe to an exploded directory.

In my experience hot deploy is unreliable in the best of cases, leaves the server in an unstable state at worst (not just jBoss, it's pretty universal).

Best to do is shut down the server, deploy an ear as Alex states, and start the server again.
jBoss startup time is good, won't cost you more than a minute or so per iteration.

Comment: it's not the production environment so the point is to make things work. the main thing is the fact that everything works fine on my colleague's computer. the only difference in our environments is that he's running winxp whether my os is ubuntu.